# explicitly collect DynamicMethod

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, garbage-collection, reflection.emit

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx):

> You can use the DynamicMethod class to generate and execute a method
>   at run time, without having to generate a dynamic assembly and a
>   dynamic type to contain the method. The executable code created by the
>   just-in-time (JIT) compiler is reclaimed when the DynamicMethod object
>   is reclaimed. Dynamic methods are the most efficient way to generate
>   and execute small amounts of code.

I have the following code:

```
Type returnType = typeof(string);
Type[] argTypes = { typeof(string), typeof(IEnumerable<string>) };

var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("DynamicMethod1", returnType, argTypes);
ILGenerator ilGen = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
const string Returned = "returned";
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, Returned);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var handler =
    (Func<string, IEnumerable<string>, string>)
    dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, IEnumerable<string>, string>));
```

i.e., i create dynamic method with some simple body, then i want to save delegate to static property. After several calls of this delegate i want to reclaim/collect method and recreate it with another body (i wrote interpreted language, that interprets my custom syntax to MSIL bytecode - something like compiler) and save new delegate to static property.

How i can explicitly collect/reclaim dynamic method?

Comment: The same way as any object in C#.  Do not reference it and allow it to be collected.

Comment: if i just remove all my references to dynamic method, i don`t know the moment when GC remove this method from memory and i don`t know when i can create new method with the same name ("DynamicMethod1").

Comment: But of course the name you pass in is utterly irrelevant for scoping purposes.  If it weren't, what would happen if some other API tried to create a method with the same name?  Just remove all references, allow it to be collected some time in the future, and create the replacement implementation whenever you feel like.  What matters is the handle to the instance of `DynamicMethod`, not its (arbitrary) name.

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi Have you actually verified that you can't do that?

Comment: i didn't tried do this. i can solve this issue another way:
i will generate method name, so dynamic methods can be collected at any time.

Comment: @svick, I verified what Dmitry said: I just duplicated the code, renaming the variables but keeping the name passed to the DynamicMethod constructor the same. It works.

Comment: You may create multiple DynamicMethod (s) with the same name, they are referenced only through the createDelegate, you can't invoke them by name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't dispose of a DynamicMethod explicitly because it doesn't implement the IDisposable interface. You can however tell the GarbageCollector when you want it to collect: `System.GC.Collect();`

This "Forces an immediate garbage collection of all generations" according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx)

Comment: Note that it is discouraged to explicitly call `GC.Collect()`

Comment: It's the way to go if you want to force collection, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. However, a full collection will stop all threads of execution. The rule of thumb is to trust the GC to collect when needed. Dynamic methods are usually lightweight and the memory pressure they impose is so low that their collection should not be a concern. It's a bit like real garbage collection, you don't ask for a citywide collection of garbage because you just deposited a single bag at the front of your house. What you do is you wait until regular garbage collection happen on a weekly basis.